# Ajax doesn't show server response

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to build a subscribe form. I can't run php on my site and I don't want the user leave the main site to subscribe the newsletter. I'm using [this example as server side](https://gist.github.com/1488819). 
If you try to put in you email you will get redirected and the error message shows up even if the e-mail was added to the mailchimp list.

```
<div id="email">
<span>Your email..</span>
<form action="http://simondahla.com/jolliassets/notify.php" id="notify" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" id="address" data-validate="validate(required, email)"/>
    <span>We'll never spam or give this address away</span>
    <button type="submit">&#187;</button>
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#notify').submit(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: $('#address').attr('value')
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data).css('color', 'green');
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#result').html('Sorry, an error occurred.').css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[live example of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/FAmFF/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Where is the code that actually does the adding to mailchimp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `false` from your submit handler. This is to prevent the browser from executing the default action, i.e. to submit the form the normal way.

```
$('#notify').submit(function() {
   // .. your ajax call
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! So I changed that. So I don't get redirected to the server, but can I pass the server response messages to the client somehow? No it only says, error to everything i try.

Answer (score 1):

From your PHP function you're going to return the values you want given the success or failure of the code.

Succeeded:

```
print json_encode(array("status"=>"success","message"=>'Successfully added'));
```

Failed:

```
print json_encode(array("status"=>"error","message"=>'There was an error'));
```

Then in the HTML you return that message like this:

```
success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(content.message).css('color', 'green');
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#result').html(content.message).css('color', 'red');
        }
```

Comment: The server writes the stuff to the database but I dont get any responses back. With the provided code. I dont get anything back actually.

Comment: Where have you got the print statement?